# Is there any way to identify references added manually vs. references added by Nuget packages?

Tags: c#, .net, dependencies

I have a solution containing projects with several hard references (added by right clicking on references and adding DLLs manually) and several installed nuget packages.

How do I distinguish between these different DLLs? I'm having lots of trouble building projects in Azure DevOps, and I suspect this has to do with why.

(If anyone would like to take this time to impart some more general dependency-fixing wisdom as well, please do.)

Comment: Wouldn't the NuGet package referenced assemblies live in the `packages` folder, while manual references live elsewhere? I'd imagine you could check the `csproj` files to see and build a lost pretty easily